# file input does not provide all file information

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my form I have:

```
<input type="file" name="data[Speciality][background_image]" id="background_image" class="hide">
```

This is request data "caught" in controller:

```
public 'data' => 
    array (size=3)
      'modified' => string '0' (length=1)
      'Speciality' => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'addfsdfsdf' (length=10)
          'background_image' => string 'test.jpg' (length=8)
```

As you see only filename is provided and it should be like this:

```
[name] => test.jpg
[type] => image/jpeg
[tmp_name] => C:\server\tmp\php5A.tmp
[error] => 0
[size] => 560
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to read the documentation on how to handle file uploads.

Make sure you got type=>file in your create() method:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Speciality', array('type' => 'file'));
```

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create